# Problem with multiple \str_case_e

Tags: conditionals, compilation-error

I have a problem if I want to use multiple `\str_case_e:nnTF`. Could you please help me how to solve this?
Is there something wrong with the `\str_case_e:nnTF` definition?
Thank you.

I use pdflatex on Mac OS:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

test.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{test}[2023/02/26 TEST LaTeX class 1.0.00]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% options
\newcommand{\project@option@language}{}
\newcommand{\project@option@type}{}

\DeclareOption{english}{\renewcommand{\project@option@language}{english}}
\DeclareOption{portuguese}{\renewcommand{\project@option@language}{portuguese}}
\DeclareOption{czech}{\renewcommand{\project@option@language}{czech}}
\DeclareOption{slovak}{\renewcommand{\project@option@language}{slovak}}

\DeclareOption{report}{\renewcommand{\project@option@type}{report}}

\DeclareOption*{\PackageError{test}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'}}

% default options
\ExecuteOptions{report,english}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% language settings
\newcommand{\project@language@english}{english}
\newcommand{\project@language@portuguese}{portuguese}
\newcommand{\project@language@czech}{czech}

% document type settings
\newcommand{\project@type@report}{report}

\ifx\project@option@type\project@type@report
    \LoadClass[a4paper,twoside,onecolumn]{article}
\fi

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ifx\project@option@language\project@language@portuguese
    \RequirePackage[brazil]{babel}
\fi
\ifx\project@option@language\project@language@czech
    \RequirePackage[czech]{babel}
\fi
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\project@authors@label}{
  \str_case_e:nnTF {\project@option@language} {
    {\project@language@portuguese} {Autores}
    {\project@language@czech} {Auto\v{r}i}
  }{
    \relax
  }{
    Authors
  }
}

\newcommand{\project@update@label}{
  \str_case_e:nnTF {\project@option@language} {
    {\project@language@portuguese} {Histórico~de~atualizações}
    {\project@language@czech} {Historie~aktualizací}
  }{
  }{
    Updates
  }
}   

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\test}{%
    \project@update@label
    \project@authors@label
}
```

test.tex

```
\documentclass[report,czech]{test} 

\begin{document}

\section{Template overview}

\test

\end{document}
```

Error log:

```
pdflatex  -halt-on-error test.tex -o test.pdf
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24> (./test.cls
Document Class: test 2023/02/26 TEST LaTeX class 1.0.00
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-czech/czech.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
 (./test.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\project@authors@label ->\str_case__e:nnTF 
                                           {\project@option@language }{{\pro...
l.7 \test
         
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe I don't quite get it, but if I compile your example, I get to error at all (using pdfLaTeX, TeX Live 2022).

Comment: `\str_case_e:nnTF` was added in 2018, if it is undefined for you that means that your format or the L3 programming layer is too old. Can you please show us the first 10 or so lines of your log (or better yet, your entire log)?

Comment: Your error shows `\str_case__e:nnTF` with two underscores

Comment: Yes, I also see two underscores in the error log but I have only one in the source. That is the point. Any help or workaround?

Comment: @MilanRusek did you check whether the error is generated by the exact code of this question? Because that one seems fine. Check whether the code in your real document has two underscores.

Comment: @Skillmon, yes, I did. This is exactly what I compiled. And this is the reason why I am asking you for help. You can try it. The example is simple, that's why it's weird. And it looks like the commands are being evaluated incorrectly somewhere.

Comment: @MilanRusek well, I did run exactly the code you provided in your question, and that doesn't err for me. Double check the definition of `\project@authors@label` in your local file, the first token of it is wrong.

Comment: Hi, there was a problem with my local machine. I reinstalled all components, and now it is working well. This package https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html helps me to solve it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not reproducible (OP resolved it themselves by installing new version).